# Why does it take so much to load 100,000 rows of data with Feeds Module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, entities

I am importing 8,000 products which have associated several items from thousands of taxonomies (nested taxonomies, 3 levels) and fields collections. I have 7 feeds which are sequenced with Elysia Cron.

I import the following, with these number of items:

1. Families, level 1: 12 (taxonomy)
2. Families, level 2: 70 (taxonomy)
3. Brands of cars, level 1: 35 (taxonomy)
4. Series of cars, level 2: 300 (taxonomy)
5. Models of cars, level 3: 3000 (taxonomy)
6. Products: 8,000 (nodes).
7. Multiple references for products: 15,000 (collection fields). It includes association of several models (point 5).

The total amount of times for the update is of 30 minutes. Isn't it too much?
There are tables in the collection_fields of around 100,000 rows.

I am worried when I will have to scale the site to have 100,000 or more products. I should I explore using fewer nested taxonomies, and use an approach with only a few taxonomies, and most of the other data, like models of car, etc., being nodes and using Relations module?

Comment: Is your only performance issue import via feeds?

Comment: Yes, everything else goes lightspeed fast.